# Guest authors, sort of like Wikipedia, but more theme-able

Tags: pages

My first post on WordPress SE.

I'm bouncing around an idea of a new site.  I want to allow for guest editing like wikipedia that someone can create articles if it doesn't exist already, existing articles can be edited, articles have edited history with IP address, allows for uploading of pictures from guest authors.

Can this be done in WordPress?  I've tried searching online, but all seems to point to having to create a login account.  I want true guest editing, without account creation.  But of course someone could create an account and do the same thing, but will have edits and contributions linked to their account name.

Edit:  I've decided against the complete guest editing option and going to opt to have them create an account.  This seems to be the easiest route.

Thanks.

Comment: The only thing i could imagine is something like a "guest comment" that would work as a temporary post... think about what that means for your db. Do you have any thoughts about the rest of the environment. I guess people would be more helpful if you share the rest of your thoughts first.

Comment: So, to give you an example of what I'm trying to do.  I've thought again about the total anonymous editing, and I don't think I'm going to allow that.  They will have to create an account.  What I want is a site that would allow users to create an account, create pages, sub-pages, upload content, edit posts/pages, and all that fun stuff.  This site will be based on information given from users about certain places where they live.  So an article parent may be the city and then sub-articles that may be other things pertaining to the users area.  Hope that explains a bit more on what I want.

Comment: why not use...a wiki ?

Comment: @anu, that's totally possible because I'm just testing solutions right now.  I'm still considering all options.  I just would like to know my options with WordPress because I believe there are more options for themes, etc.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yup, you probably get a greater choice of themes with WordPress, but given that you'll need to hack the hell out of the theme, I think this is a limited benefit. Given how much of the functionality that you're talking about fits with a wiki's feature set, I'd say it would be easier to theme a wiki than to make WP act like one. Having said that, there are some plugins that enhance WP with wiki functionality - I'll add them as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I would check this plugin out. I allows guests to create posts but not sure about editing live posts. >

**Anonymous Posting**

It allows anonymous users/readers to write their own posts, writing is protected with reCAPTCHA. Plugin can be used for some kind of message board or public forum, you can configure comments under anonymous posts. Writing is avaialbe via special page/post.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/anon-posting/

Comment: I've updated what I want in the comment section of the question.  Sorry, I don't think your answer pertains to my question anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to require accounts first, then the Front End Editor plugin ([link to codex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/)) should handle it nicely. It allows for user editing and tracks modifications, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [WordPress Wiki](http://wp-wiki.org/) or the [WordPress wiki theme](http://wpwikitheme.com/).